# Inequality with a point $P$ in a plane and four points on a line

Tags: geometry

I randomly found this question in a book and I don't know how to approach or solve this problem.
I appreciate both an approach or a full prove. :)

"Let $A, B, C$ and $D$ be points on a line $g$ in this order.

a) Show: If the inequality $\overline{AP}+\overline{DP} \geq \overline{BP}+\overline{CP}$ holds for every point $P$ on $g$,
then $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$.

b) Show: If the inequality $\overline{AP}+\overline{DP} >\overline{BP}+\overline{CP}$  holds for every point $P$ on the plane that is not on g,
then $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to note that P in case b) doesn't lie on g

Comment: But I would be thankful for a prove ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A,B,C,D$ are points from left to right on $g$.

$(a)$ Take $P$ to the left of $A$ on $g$ and note that $$\overline{AP}+\overline{DP} \geq \overline{BP}+\overline{CP} \implies \overline{DP}-\overline{CP} \geq \overline{BP}-\overline{AP} \implies \overline{CD}\ge \overline{AB} \tag1$$ since here $\overline{DP}-\overline{CP}=\overline{CD}, \overline{BP}-\overline{AP}=\overline{AB}$. Similarly, taking $P$ to the right of $D$ on $g$, we get $$\overline{AP}+\overline{DP} \geq \overline{BP}+\overline{CP} \implies \overline{AP}-\overline{BP} \geq \overline{CP}-\overline{DP} \implies \overline{AB}\ge \overline{CD} \tag2$$ and from $(1),(2)$ we get $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$

Comment: I am wondering why we only need to look at the cases for which P is either on the left side of A or on the right side of D. What is with the cases, where p lies between these points and why don't we have to consider them.

Comment: It's already given that $P$ lies on the line $g$, taking it on the extremes helps us to get $\overline{AB}=|\overline{BP}-\overline{AP}|$ which would not be true if $P$ lies in between $A,B$. Obviously, you can look at cases where $P$ lies in between these points, but you're required to prove $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$, so I have considered $P$ at all positions and written in the solution only those cases which help in proving $\overline{AB}=\overline{CD}$. You have to put $P$ in various positions and use geometrical knowledge/intutition to check what they yield.

Comment: For e.g given points $U,V$ on a plane, any point on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $\overline{UV}$ has equal distance from $U$ and $V$, (you can prove using congruent triangles) so that in part $(b)$, if you put $P$ on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$ in the question, you will have $\overline{AP}=\overline{BP} \implies \overline{DP}>\overline{CP}$ (which is true anyway, but this is just an example of what I mean in the previous comment.)

Comment: Could you please write a complete proof for b)? ^^

Comment: And is your proof for a) a complete proof?

Comment: That is indeed a complete proof for $(a)$. I will give ample hint for part $(b)$ (if I can solve it myself) by editing the question and let you try it on your own.

Comment: Okay thank you :)